# Best way to get 'git cat-file' output from a remote repository?

Tags: git, github, commit

I am trying to retrieve commit data from remote repositories programmatically. When I say *commit data*, I mean the inputs passed in to SHA-1 to generate the hash. For example:

Which you could normally get if you `git cat-file -p <a-commit-hash>` in some local repository.

After a pretty thorough search, I am struggling to find a method that works for remote that doesn't involve cloning the entire repository just to get one commit.

If it has to use Github API to do this efficiently, then that works, but I am not even sure that is possible and would like some advice for doing that.

For pure git methods, I have heard you can retrieve a single *file* doing something like

```
git archive --remote=git@gitserver.example.com:myrepo master path/to/file1 | tar -xOf - > file1
```

But could that be modified to work for commits as well?

Any other alternatives here?

Comment: `git archive` doesn't work with Github — disabled at Github side.

Comment: The current transport protocol supports "partial cloning" by allowing any client to ask for any hash ID, so you can do it that way *if* the server supports it. There's no Git tool for doing this directly though (probably there should be, it would just invoke the right bits of the transport code directly). That aside, the only *guaranteed* method is to clone. Note that you can do a partial and shallow clone with filtering and then use `git cat-file` on the result, to sidestep the lack of a more direct tool.